# RapidMiner - Country prediction from addresses

Tags: mysql, r, machine-learning, prediction, rapidminer

I am new to predictive analytics. I am trying to extract country codes (ISO) from different addresses. I have a database with all possible countries (dbname: Geo) and their respective ISO codes.
I am trying to use Rapid Miner or R as a starting point (and also SQL)

For example:

Address: 123 Main St 54321 US/CA

Results: 1) US 2) CA

What would be the best approach to make a predictive model to find the country names?

Right now I am just using sql:

```
DECLARE db_cursor_country CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  COUNTRY_NAME 
    FROM    TScotiaCountryUpdated
    --WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',COUNTRY_NAME,0) > 0

OPEN db_cursor_country;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_country INTO @Country



WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   

    INSERT INTO TCountryNameMatch
    SELECT  FT.[Rank] ,
            TPartyNameAddress.PartyNameAddress,
            @Country AS Country_Name,
            CC_ISO
            ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(PartyNameAddress, 20) LIKE '%UNITED STATES%' OR PartyNameAddress LIKE '%NEW YORK%' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END  AS USFlag
            --INTO dbo.TCountryNameMatch 
    FROM    TPartyNameAddress
            INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(TPartyNameAddress, PartyNameAddress, @Country) FT ON FT.[Key] = TPartyNameAddress.ID
            INNER   JOIN TScotiaCountryUpdated ON @Country= COUNTRY_NAME

            PRINT @Country
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_country INTO @Country


END;
CLOSE db_cursor_country;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor_country;`
```

Comment: is the country always in the text, but simply in different formats?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yeah it is always a text but in different formats. I am currently looking at city name, state name , zipcodes , ISO codes and country names.

Comment: so you are probably looking at "data mining" techniques then machine learning. It does not look like a good task for ML. You can solve it using it, but it might be an overkill, which might be more efficiently solved by old good regexes etc.